# Failing to parse complex JSON using Python and Marshmallow

Tags: python, marshmallow

I am using Marshmallow to create a mapper for a JSON file. Following are the details:

My JSON File:

```
{
    "version": "3.0",
    "name": "A1",
    "request": {
        "startdate": "26022022",
        "enddate": "26022022",
        "records": 1000
    },
    "ranking": {
        "90": {
            "name": "N1",
            "class1": "C1"
        },
        "98": {
            "name": "N2",
            "class1": "C2"
        },
        "86": {
            "name": "N3",
            "class1": "C3"
        }
    }
}
```

My mapper class:

```
class RequestMapper(Schema):
    startdate = fields.String()
    enddate = fields.String()
    records = fields.Int()

class Ranking(Schema):
    name = fields.String()
    class1 = fields.String()

class RankingMapper(Schema):
    rank = fields.Nested(Ranking(), dataKey = fields.Int)

class SampleSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    request = fields.Nested(RequestMapper())
    ranking = fields.Nested(RankingMapper())
```

Code to call Mapper:

```
        print("\n\nOutput using mapper")
        pprint(mapper.SampleSchema().dump(data), indent=3)
        print("\n\n")
```

Following is the output:

```
Output using mapper
{  'name': 'A1',
   'ranking': {},
   'request': {'enddate': '26022022', 'records': 1000, 'startdate': '26022022'}}
```

I am not getting any data for ranking as datakey [90, 98, 86...] are dynamic and am not sure how to create mapper for dynamic keys please.

Any inputs will be helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When nesting schemas, pass the class NAME, not a class instance:

```
class RankingMapper(Schema):
    rank = fields.Nested(Ranking, dataKey = fields.Int)

class SampleSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    request = fields.Nested(RequestMapper)
    ranking = fields.Nested(RankingMapper)
```

Comment: Hi @Tim Roberts, Thank you for the inputs. I agree, I should be passing class name in place of class instance. By the way any inputs on actual problem please i.e. handling dynamic keys. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure `marshmallow` can handle that, but someone will surely jump on me if I am wrong.  You may just need to do this mapping yourself.  Your structure is not that complicated.

Comment: Hi @Tim Roberts, Thank you again. Could you please point me to an example to do mapping myself please? Thank you

Comment: Well, that depends on what you need.  To get the names of each ranking, it's just `for k,v in data['ranking'].items():` / `print("Ranking", k, "is name", v['name'])`.

Comment: Thank you @Tim Roberts. I understood what you meant by mapping yourself. I was looking to use library like marshmallow which gives the following benefits over manual mapping: 1. Automatic mapping of schema. 2. We can extend or modify the schema easily if input json changes. 3. We can apply validations. 4. We can add additional attributes. Those were couple of reason, I was opting for pre-available library but unfortunately I am not able to handle dynamic ranking keys.

Comment: Well, it's not really "automatic".  You have to define it all by hand, it's always going to have limitations like this, and it breaks if the JSON changes.  By using dicts and lists, your code will still work even if new thing are added.